# Clarification about a statement in Graph Theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What does this statement mean:

> "Unlike Eulerian circuits, there is **no known necessary and
>   sufficient condition** for a graph to be Hamiltonian."

I'm confused about the "no known necessary and sufficient condition " phrase. Thanks

Comment: I think it means a condition $X$ such that a graph is Hamiltonian if and only if $X$ holds. As pointed out by Robert Israel, this is not true, since a definition is trivially such condition. If I were to speculate, it might mean "no simple condition" (with "simple" being the key word that actually can mean anything) or "a condition known to be in $P$" (since we don't know whether $P = NP$).

Comment: Cited from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/130528/19341): *A lot of sufficient conditions for Hamiltonian graphs are [surveyed here.](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2000/vol1-n1/paper4/v1n1-4pd.PDF)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated, this is simply false: the definition of Hamiltonian is a necessary and sufficient condition.  What is true is that there is no known necessary and sufficient condition that is easy to decide: more technically, there is no known decision procedure that runs in polynomial time.

If you're asking what "necessary and sufficient condition" means: a necessary and sufficient condition for $S$  is a statement $C$ that logically equivalent to $S$, i.e. is true whenever $S$ is true, and false whenever $S$ is false.   A necessary condition is one that is true whenever $S$ is true.  A sufficient condition is one that is false whenever $S$ is false.

Comment: +1 for a good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

A "necessary and sufficient condition" for something means an "if and only if" condition.

More generally, if someone says that $A$ is a sufficient condition for $B$, it means that $A$ implies $B$.  (Because in that case, knowing that $A$ true is *sufficient* to guarantee that $B$ is also true.)

Saying that $A$ is a necessary condition for $B$ means that $B$ implies $A$.  (Because then it's *necessary* for $A$ to be true if you want to have any hope of $B$ being true.)

So saying that $A$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $B$ just means $A \iff B$.

Answer (score 2):

Robert is correct, I would like to add that regardless of this being a 'hard problem' I believe this means that we don't have a 'good' characterizations other than the definition.

Comment: Also, if it is combinatorics that you study - don't let this sentence bother you, it is related to computer scince theory called computability theory